# Regex not extracting all matching words

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract words that have at least one character from a special character set. It picks up some words and not others. [Here is a link](https://regex101.com/r/ovJoLt/1) to regex101 to test it. This it the regex `\b(\w*[āīūẓḍḥṣṭĀĪŪẒḌḤṢṬʿʾ]+\w*)\b`, and this is the sample sentence I am using

> His full name is Abu ʿĪsa Muḥammad ibn ʿĪsa ibn Sawrah ibn Mūsa ibn
>   Al-Daḥāk Al-Sulamī Al-Tirmidhī.

It should match the following words:

> ʿĪsa Muḥammad ʿĪsa Mūsa Al-Daḥāk Al-Sulamī Al-Tirmidhī

I am not too experienced with regex, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong. If someone knows any tool to find out why a specific word doesn't match a regex pattern, please let me know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[\w-]*[āīūẓḍḥṣṭĀĪŪẒḌḤṢṬʿʾ][\wāīūẓḍḥṣṭĀĪŪẒḌḤṢṬʿʾ-]*
```

After matching the one required special character, use another character set to match more occurrences of those characters *or* normal word characters.

https://regex101.com/r/ovJoLt/2

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by enabling the Unicode flag `/u` (so that the word boundary `\b` assertions support Unicode characters) and adding hyphens to the surrounding character groups:

```
/\b[\w-]*[āīūẓḍḥṣṭĀĪŪẒḌḤṢṬʿʾ]+[\w-]*\b/gu
```

Plus, you don't need the capturing group, since the only characters being matched form the desired output anyway (`\b` is a zero-width assertion).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovJoLt/4)

Comment: I just realized that it was set to PHP and it doesn't work if I switch to JavaScript. What could I do to fix it in JavaScript?

Comment: @user1807157 I believe that CertainPerformance's answer works with JavaScript regex engines and is simpler to read than trying to fix what is in my answer currently, so that's what I would recommend. The problem is that `\b` does not support Unicode with JS regex.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I went ahead and accepted his instead since it works better for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing anything wrong except that to match unicode boundaries you have to enable `u` modifier or use `(?<!\S)\w*[āīūẓḍḥṣṭĀĪŪẒḌḤṢṬʿʾ]+\w*(?!\S)`

If you want to match hyphen add it to your character class `(?<!\S)\w*[āīūẓḍḥṣṭĀĪŪẒḌḤṢṬʿʾ-]+\w*(?!\S)`